# how to close when i click the x button

Tags: javascript, html

I'm doing **todo list** and when I click the x button it won't close

I'm expecting when I click the close button it will close

```js
const displayNote = document.querySelector('.js-button');
const clearNote = document.querySelector('.js-exit');
const closeButton = document.querySelectorAll('#get-close');

function exit() {
  document.querySelector('.pops').classList.remove('active-pops');
}

function openNote() {
  document.querySelector('.pops').classList.add('active-pops');
}

clearNote.addEventListener('click', () => {
  exit();
});

displayNote.addEventListener('click', () => {
  openNote();
});


function putNewContext() {
  const title = document.querySelector('#get-title');
  const paragraph = document.querySelector('#get-paragraph');

  let html = `
  <div class="your-note">
  <div class="container">
    <span id="get-close">X</span>
    <h2>${title.value}</h2>
    <p>${paragraph.value}</p>
  </div>
</div>
  `;

  return html;
}

document.querySelector('.js-enter-btn').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.querySelector('#note-container').innerHTML += putNewContext();
});


function attachCloseListeners() {
  const closeButton = document.querySelectorAll('#get-close');
  closeButton.forEach((button) => {
    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
      button.parentNode.parentNode.remove(); // Removes the entire note container
    });
  });
}

attachCloseListeners();
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

body {
  background: rgb(1, 1, 93);
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px 5%;
}

#container {
  padding: 30px 10%;
}

#container button {
  color: white;
  background-color: rgb(192, 0, 192);
  padding: 10px 30px;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: transform 0.5s, background-color 0.5s;
  border: none;
}

#container button:hover {
  transform: translateY(-5px);
  background-color: rgb(253, 148, 253);
}

.pops {
  padding: 30px 3%;
  width: 30%;
  height: 65vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: rgb(115, 115, 115);
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 30%;
  display: none;
}

.pops.active-pops {
  display: block;
}

.pops span {
  color: red;
  font-size: 1.7rem;
  margin-left: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.pops .inner-pops {
  width: 100%;
}

.pops .inner-pops button {
  padding: 5px 14px;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

.pops .ultra-inner-pops {
  color: white;
  margin-top: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.pops .ultra-inner-pops input {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
}

.pops .ultra-inner-pops textarea {
  width: 100%;
}

#note-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 1%;
}

#note-container .your-note {
  width: 30%;
  margin-top: 3%;
}

#note-container .your-note .container {
  background: linear-gradient(rgb(40, 197, 202), rgb(209, 0, 228));
  padding: 15px 30px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  height: 100%;
}

#note-container .your-note .container h2 {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-align: center;
}

#note-container .your-note .container p {
  font-weight: 500;
}

#note-container .your-note .container span {
  margin-left: 100%;
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/*# sourceMappingURL=quiz.css.map */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>todo list</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/quiz/quiz.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div id="container">
    <button class="js-button">Make a note</button>
  </div>

  <div class="pops">
    <span class="js-exit">X</span>
    <div class="inner-pops">
      <div class="ultra-inner-pops">
        <h2>Title</h2>
        <input id="get-title" type="text">
      </div>

      <div class="ultra-inner-pops">
        <h2>Description</h2>
        <textarea id="get-paragraph" cols="30" rows="15"></textarea>
      </div>
      <button class="js-enter-btn">Enter</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="note-container">

  </div>



  <script src="/quiz/quiz.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make it a class and delegate

```
container.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const tgt = e.target.closest("span.get-close");
  if (!tgt) return; // not the close button
  tgt.closest(".your-note").remove(); // Removes the entire note container
});
```

Like this

```js
const displayNote = document.querySelector('.js-button');
const clearNote = document.querySelector('.js-exit');
const container = document.querySelector('#note-container')

function exit() {
  document.querySelector('.pops').classList.remove('active-pops');
}

function openNote() {
  document.querySelector('.pops').classList.add('active-pops');
}

clearNote.addEventListener('click', () => {
  exit();
});

displayNote.addEventListener('click', () => {
  openNote();
});


function putNewContext() {
  const title = document.querySelector('#get-title');
  const paragraph = document.querySelector('#get-paragraph');

  let html = `
  <div class="your-note">
  <div class="container">
    <span class="get-close">X</span>
    <h2>${title.value}</h2>
    <p>${paragraph.value}</p>
  </div>
</div>
  `;

  return html;
}

document.querySelector('.js-enter-btn').addEventListener('click', () => {
  container.innerHTML += putNewContext();
});


container.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const tgt = e.target.closest("span.get-close");
  if (!tgt) return; // not the close button
  tgt.closest(".your-note").remove(); // Removes the entire note container
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

body {
  background: rgb(1, 1, 93);
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px 5%;
}

#container {
  padding: 30px 10%;
}

#container button {
  color: white;
  background-color: rgb(192, 0, 192);
  padding: 10px 30px;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: transform 0.5s, background-color 0.5s;
  border: none;
}

#container button:hover {
  transform: translateY(-5px);
  background-color: rgb(253, 148, 253);
}

.pops {
  padding: 30px 3%;
  width: 30%;
  height: 65vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: rgb(115, 115, 115);
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 30%;
  display: none;
}

.pops.active-pops {
  display: block;
}

.pops span {
  color: red;
  font-size: 1.7rem;
  margin-left: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.pops .inner-pops {
  width: 100%;
}

.pops .inner-pops button {
  padding: 5px 14px;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

.pops .ultra-inner-pops {
  color: white;
  margin-top: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.pops .ultra-inner-pops input {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
}

.pops .ultra-inner-pops textarea {
  width: 100%;
}

#note-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 1%;
}

#note-container .your-note {
  width: 30%;
  margin-top: 3%;
}

#note-container .your-note .container {
  background: linear-gradient(rgb(40, 197, 202), rgb(209, 0, 228));
  padding: 15px 30px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  height: 100%;
}

#note-container .your-note .container h2 {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-align: center;
}

#note-container .your-note .container p {
  font-weight: 500;
}

#note-container .your-note .container span {
  margin-left: 100%;
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/*# sourceMappingURL=quiz.css.map */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>todo list</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/quiz/quiz.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div id="container">
    <button class="js-button">Make a note</button>
  </div>

  <div class="pops">
    <span class="js-exit">X</span>
    <div class="inner-pops">
      <div class="ultra-inner-pops">
        <h2>Title</h2>
        <input id="get-title" type="text">
      </div>

      <div class="ultra-inner-pops">
        <h2>Description</h2>
        <textarea id="get-paragraph" cols="30" rows="15"></textarea>
      </div>
      <button class="js-enter-btn">Enter</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="note-container">

  </div>



  <script src="/quiz/quiz.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```